# Benchmarking NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

I'm trying to make a case for a machine with a SSD at work. Is there a way to benchmark NetBeans?

WulfgarPro

Comment: I'd be very interested to know what your results are, as I'm scheming to get myself a new dev machine with a SSD :)

Comment: @Tim Sparg - i'll keep you posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Christoph Amshoff](http://javamoods.blogspot.com/2010/04/hdd-ssd-battle.html) wrote about this with Eclipse, So you can maybe try to run your tests along the same line, or use his tests as part of your research.